# Reading excel file in python with pandas and multiple indices

Tags: python, excel, pandas, timestamp

I am a python newbie so please excuse this basic question. 
My .xlsx File looks like this

```
Unnamend:1    A     Unnamend:2    B
2015-01-01    10    2015-01-01    10
2015-01-02    20    2015-01-01    20
2015-01-03    30    NaT           NaN
```

When I read it in Python using pandas.read_excel(...) pandas automatically uses the first column as the time index.

Is there a one-liner that tells pandas to notice, that every second column is a time index belonging to the time series right next to it?

The desired output would look like this:

```
date          A     B
2015-01-01    10    10
2015-01-02    20    20
2015-01-03    30    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to parse chunks of adjacent `columns` and align on their respective `datetime` indexes, you can do the following:

Starting with `df`:

```
Int64Index: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Unnamed: 0    3 non-null datetime64[ns]
A             3 non-null int64
Unnamed: 1    2 non-null datetime64[ns]
B             2 non-null float64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float64(1), int64(1)
```

You could iterate over chunks of 2 columns and `merge` on `index` like so:

```
def chunks(l, n):
    """ Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

merged = df.loc[:, list(df)[:2]].set_index(list(df)[0])
for cols in chunks(list(df)[2:], 2):
    merged = merged.merge(df.loc[:, cols].set_index(cols[0]).dropna(), left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
```

to get:

```
             A   B
2015-01-01  10  10
2015-01-01  10  20
2015-01-02  20 NaN
2015-01-03  30 NaN
```

`pd.concat` unfortunately doesn't work as it can't handle duplicate `index` entries, otherwise one could use a `list comprehension`:

```
pd.concat([df.loc[:, cols].set_index(cols[0]) for cols in chunks(list(df), 2)], axis=1)
```

Comment: Hi Stefan. Assume that in my example Series A and B switch the index, such that B is now the longest series. Wound´t that lead to missing index values (i.e. missing "2015-01-03") if I choose index_col=0 by default?

Comment: Indeed. One would also think you'd like to merge the columns on the dates. If that's not necessary, we can add a step where the longest `column` becomes the `index`. If you want to `merge` instead we'd have of course to take a different approach.

Comment: Whats the exact difference between merging and taking the longest index aligning all other series on that index? I come from R and here the magic word indeed is "merge" or cbind...

Comment: Difference is alignment - do you want the values to align on dates or just maintain the row order?

Answer (score 0):

I use xlrd for import the data, after i use pandas to display

```
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(xls_name)
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(xls_name, encoding_override="cp1252")
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
first_row = [] # The row where we stock the name of the column
for col in range(worksheet.ncols):
    first_row.append( worksheet.cell_value(0,col) )
data =[]
for row in range(10, worksheet.nrows):
    elm = {}
    for col in range(worksheet.ncols):
          elm[first_row[col]]=worksheet.cell_value(row,col)
    data.append(elm)

first_column=second_column=third_column=[]
for elm in data :
    first_column.append(elm(first_row[0]))
    second_column.append(elm(first_row[1]))
    third_column.append(elm(first_row[2]))

dict1={}
dict1[first_row[0]]=first_column
dict1[first_row[1]]=second_column
dict1[first_row[2]]=third_column
res=pd.DataFrame(dict1, columns=['column1', 'column2', 'column3'])
print res
```